# Store retrieved data from indexed DB to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization, indexeddb

I am using the following code to read data from Indexed DB and save it in variable allDownloadContent

```
ereaderdownload.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems = function() {

    /*var todos = document.getElementById("todoItems");
    todos.innerHTML = "";
  */
    var db = ereaderdownload.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction(["downloadcontent"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore("downloadcontent");
    var request = store.get(0);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
    };

    // Get everything in the store;
    var cursorRequest = store.openCursor();
    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
        if(!!result == false)
            return;
        allDownloadContent.push(result);
        result.continue();
    };
    alert("content "+allDownloadContent[0]);
    cursorRequest.onerror = ereaderdownload.indexedDB.onerror;
  };
```

When I call the getAllTodoItems method from another Javascript file I am getting a alert message **content undefined**

since the **cursorRequest.onsuccess** method executes async I am getting undefined.

I cannot make use of web workers since it is not supported in chrome.

I tried promise in Jquery. Still I am getting the same alert message.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by web workers aren't supported in Chrome ? http://caniuse.com/webworkers

Comment: I mean sync indexeddb api

Comment: I guess you want to alert in the callback where you've coded `return`. At that time the data is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for now all browsers only support the Indexed-db ASync API, and what you need to do is add an event listener to the transaction `oncomplete` event. This event will fire when cursor is closed. From there you can return to your code:

```
trans.oncomplete = function (event) {
    console.log('transaction completed');
    yourFunction();
};
```